# Is this regular expression?

Tags: regex, unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is how to split string in Unityscript from Unity Wiki. However, I don't recognize `" "[0]`. Is this regular expression? If so, any reference to it? I'm familiar with regular expressions generally and used them a lot, but this syntax is little confusing.

```
var qualifiedName = "System.Integer myInt";

var name = qualifiedName.Split(" "[0]);
```

[Wiki Reference](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Head_First_into_Unity_with_JavaScript)

Comment: It's just that " " is a String, which is an array of characters. " "[0] means the first character of the string (which is, again, ' ').

Comment: Mono doc suggest this is regex, but I don't understand why `' '` couldn't be used...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many have already mentioned, `" "[0]` is the first character of the `" "` string (which is a `System.String`, or an array of `System.Char`s. The problem with UnityScript is that `' '` is interpreted as a String too, so the only way to provide a Char is by slicing.

Comment: `split` function needs `string` as delimeter, not `char`. See [here](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aJava.Lang.String.Split(string))

Comment: I think you are looking at methods for `Java.Lang.String` instead of `System.String` (as seen [here](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aSystem.String.Split(char%5b%5d))), which is the one used by .NET and Unity.

Comment: ah, you are right! I thought if the language I am scripting is Javascript, then I should look at `Java.Lang.String`. So in the docs I should always look at `System.` prefix...

Answer (score 5):

On any string, wether it is a variable or a literal (" "), you can use an indexer to get the char at the nth position.

Your codesample is a very weird way of literally defining a char with a space, and could be simplified by using this:

```
' '
```

note the single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: is there actually any significance of single quotes? Since `" "===' '` returns true

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking in .net syntax!

Comment: Which is the correct syntax to think in for this question. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

`" "[0]` is the first character of the string `" "`.

```
typeof " "[0]; // "string"
```

Your example is strange, because `" "[0]` and `" "` are strictly equal.

```
" "[0] === " "; // true
```

Reading [reference](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Head_First_into_Unity_with_JavaScript):

> Mono Types When a Mono function requires a char as an input, you can
>   obtain one by simply indexing a string. E.g. if you wanted to pass the
>   lowercase a as a char, you'd write: "a"[0]

I suppose it's because UnityScript is implemented in Boo and String is provided by mono.

Comment: but why not using just `' '` or `" "`?

Comment: God knows... " "[0] === " "

Comment: I mentioned wiki reference in my question, in case I missed something.

Comment: It's something in the UnityScript implementation. Even if in Javascript they are the same, in the implemention it can be faster, because is treated like a `char`.

Comment: I understand, but looking into [split](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aJava.Lang.String.Split(string)) I see that it wants `string`, not `char`.